# "To live" vs "for living in"

Tags: word-usage

I was wondering which is the correct form for expressing this simple concept in a formal way: " my hometown is a good place FOR LIVING IN / TO LIVE ".

Grammatically I would say that "my hometown is a good place for living in" is correct, but I see a lot of people that write "my hometown is a good place to live".

Answer (score 1):

> "My hometown is a good place for living in."
>
> "My hometown is a good place to live".

They are both grammatically correct and it could be argued that the meaning is the same.

For me there is a difference.

"My hometown is a good place for living in."  This means that my hometown has good facilities: cinemas, music venues, sports arenas, restaurants etc.  The town supports the everyday activities of living.

"My hometown is a good place to live". This could mean the same but to me it means that it is good because it is in a good location or is situated somewhere important. For example:

*"My hometown is a good place to live because it is near the university that I want to attend. I'll be able to visit my parents and friends regularly".*

Comment: I think the second sentence should end with "in" as "live" is used as an intransitive verb.

Comment: @Rathony, look at the first 8 book titles in this Google Books search -> https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22place+to+live%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1993,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=ss41Vtz-GIP8abSPmPAP -> Then page down and keep looking.     Although your idea has logic, it doesn't accord with actual usage.

Comment: I always think we have to distinguish English usages used in "book titles" and "headlines" from normal usages in above sentences. I would say "I am living in London" and "I am living London" have diffrent connotations and "London is a better place to live in" and "London is a better place to live" do, too unless they are written in "book titles".

Comment: I only mentioned titles because they came first on that list. If you keep scrolling/paging down the list you will eventually see the same idiom occurring in the body text as well.  I'm not saying that a sentence *cannot* end with "place to live in" because that idiom is used occasionally (usually with in a slightly different meaning).  However it isn't idiomatic in this particular case.  If you want to discuss it further then I think that would have to be a different question as it is off-topic here.  P.S. The idiom applies to to other intransitive verbs as well.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Do you mind if I post a question on this citing your examples?

Comment: No problem. Go ahead.

Comment: I have just posted [it](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/284081/to-live-in-vs-to-live). Please take a look to see if there is any misleading part. Your comment and edition are welcome.

Comment: TL;DR the link: it's because, "The noun *place* is not a normal noun."