# "It was the kind of story that / where you had to be there." -- Are the relative words 'where' and 'that' interchangeable? What does 'where' mean?

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

Consider this exchange:

> A: *Your story wasn't funny at all.*
> B: *Maybe it was the kind of story **where** you had to be there.*

I encountered something like that a few days ago, and wondered if the relative word *where* could be replaced with *that*:

> <sup>?</sup>*Maybe it was the kind of story **that** you had to be there.*

It sounded strange a bit, but I was reluctant to say it's wrong, because there are analogous examples where a *that* relative or bare relative could be used instead of a *where* relative clause:

> - The place I went running was a few blocks away

- This is not the place I will die.
- It's pathetic to live in the place you grew up.
- If you would have told me a year ago that I'd be in the place that I am now, I would have been like, good joke.
- Why does poetry become the place that you can say it?

> 

<sup>examples from [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/)</sup>

So, when is it possible to use the relative words *that* and *where* interchangeably?

Comment: Where did you get that sentence? What does it mean? Most importantly "where" is not a relative pronoun. Just because you find other sentences **where** "where" is replaced by "that" doesn't mean you can change it in every sentence.

Answer (score 4):

In the first example (*the story where...*), 'story' is thought of as a place *in* which some events happened, and we want to talk about the events that happened *in* the story, not the story itself. That's what *where* does here: it ushers us into the story, (which is metaphorically thought of as a place,) to show us what goes on *in* there. That's why a *where* relative clause can be rephrased into an *in which* relative clause:

> the house *where* I grew up => the house *which* I grew up *in*
>   the kind of story *where* you had to be there => the kind of story *in which* you had to be

But a *that* clause is normally a statement about a thing (itself, or something related to it), not what goes on *in* that thing (as a place):

> The story *that* B told was not funny.

In the example above, B told the story itself. There's no suggestion as to what happened in the story.

That's the general rule about relative words *where* and *that*. However, there's an exception to that rule, and that's when the head noun (the noun described by the relative clause; e.g., *man* in *the man that came*) is ***place***. A good explanation and many more examples can be found [**here**](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/284226). I'll cite a couple authorities on this matter too.

- From *A Student's Introduction to English Grammar* by Huddleston and Pullum, p. 185 (adapted):

  > The non-wh construction is not always available when the relativised element is
  >   adjunct (or complement) of place; the example *a place (that) you can relax*, with the head noun *place*, is perfectly acceptable, but in sentences with head nouns less likely to suggest location, a *wh* relative would normally be required. That is, we would say *This is the web page **where** the claim was first made*, not **This is the web page the claim was first made.*
- From *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* by Rodney Huddleston and  Geoffrey K. Pullum, p. 1053 (adapted):

  > Relatives introduced by *when*† ... have non-*wh* counterparts, with or without *that*:
  >
  > - i *I haven't seen them since the day [when/(that) Kim was born].*
  >     ...
  >
  > Relatives introduced by *where*, by contrast, do not in general alternate with the non-*wh* type except where the antecedent is a very general noun such as *place*:
  >
  > - i *This is much better than the hotel [where we stayed last year]*
  > - ii *This is much better than the place [where/(<sup>?</sup>that) we stayed last year]*
  >
  > The <sup>(?)</sup> annotation in [ii] applies to the version with *that* (<sup>?</sup>*the place that we stayed last year*); the bare relative (*the place we stayed last year*) is more acceptable.
  >   The restriction to *wh* relatives does not apply when *where* is complement to stranded *at*: *the hotel where/(that) we stayed at last  year*. *Where ... at* seems to be a blend between *where* and *which ... at*; note that with *in* we can have *which* but not *where*: *the hotel which/*where we stayed in last year*.

Are there any nouns besides *place* that have this quality? I don't know, but the citations above don't seem to assert that there aren't.

---

† <sub>I guess partly due to the fact that you don't usually think of things as periods of time: **the story when you had to be there*, so the problem doesn't arise in the first place.</sub>

Comment: Please say more about the non-wh in "place that you can relax". It sounds to me that the head is not place...to use "that" with "place" I would want to switch the positions: "this is the kind of place that can relax you". "Place" doesn't mean "location" in the example you provided above?

Comment: That example is from the cited book. It's not mine to expand on. If you don't find it clear, please refer to the _the place that_ examples in the Original Post. They are all alike.

Comment: But I don't see your COCA examples as exceptions at all. All of them, except for the second, are typical cases of relative clauses. E.g., *She took me to the place that I always wanted to go **to***; *Where the human remains were found was behind a home that nobody was living **in** at the time.*) As for the second example, *If you would have told me a year ago that I'd be in the place that I am now, I would have been like, good joke*, I think we probably can think of it as the *in* is shared by *I'd be* and *I am*.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Agreed and edited accordingly.

Comment: @BeaBonmot I edited and added a good link on _place + relative clause_.

Comment: *Where* isn't a relative pronoun.  Traditionally, it's a relative adverb; in H&P's grammar, it's a relative preposition.

Comment: This is an excellent answer! Perhaps there are other words like *place*, but not many. By the way, *the place that...* (in the construction mentioned) is casual or informal.

Comment: @snailboat The glossary of _A Student's Introduction to English Grammar_ says: "**Relative pronoun:** One of the pronouns _who_, _which_, _what_, etc. as used in a relative clause or fused relative construction: _He 's the one [who caused the trouble]_; _[What she said] is true._" Maybe I'm misunderstanding the definition, or they used different terms in their books. Anyway, I'll change it to _relative word_. I hope that's okay.

Comment: That description doesn't disagree with what I wrote. *Who, what*, and *which* are pronouns (although *what* can also be a determinative), but not all relative words are pronouns.

Answer (score 4):

When you replace *where* with *that* or *which*, sometimes you need to add a preposition.
For example,

> This is the company where he works,

becomes

> This is the company that he works at.

How do you figure out which preposition? Rearrange the relative clause so it forms its own sentence. You can't say

> You were there the story,

so you need a preposition.
The right preposition is

> You were there **for** the story.

The proper grammar is thus

> Maybe it was the kind of story (that) you had to be there **for**,

where the *that* is optional.

Comment: Nice guideline, but two things: a) I think in the _story_ example, _where_ strongly suggests that the relative clause is describing a (metaphorical) location. Therefore, _for_ is not the best choice because it's not a preposition of location. b) There are some exceptions where after replacing _where_ with _that_, there's no need for a preposition: _This is the place where we first met_ => _This is the place that we first met_.

Comment: (a) I can't think of a better choice of preposition than *for*. (b) I said in the first line that *sometimes* you need to add a preposition.

Comment: This is the correct answer. +1) The *where* in the sentence cannot be replaced by "that" because of *there*. Question to Peter Shor: Don't you think the *there* in the original sentence should not be there or the sentence sounds wrong because of "there"?