# Is it correct to use where in a sentence like this?

Tags: grammar, when, where

> I don't want you to do things where you put your hand on the back of my head.

I saw this use of where and wondering is it right use or "when" should use in stead of where.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of the relative adverb where in 'a case where'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/494077/use-of-the-relative-adverb-where-a-case-where)? Or  ["It was the kind of story that / where you had to be there." -- Are the relative words 'where' and 'that' interchangeable?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/322431/it-was-the-kind-of-story-that-where-you-had-to-be-there-are-the-relative)

Answer (score 0):

- I don't want you to do things where you put your hand on the back of my head.

It depends on what the speaker means by this sentence.

1. (*When, where*) While  you have your hand on the back of my head, I don't want you to do things. (*"When" is probably better.*)
2. (*Where, when*) At the point in time where your hand gets on the back of my head, I don't want you to be doing things. (*One seems as good as the other, but someone might insist on "when"*.)
3. (*Where*)  I don't want you to do things at the place where you put your hand at the back of my head. (*It might be the top, the bottom, the sides. "When" is not proper in this context.*)